# could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ubuntu-sdk

Tags: application-development, qt, ubuntu-sdk

Command:

```
$ ubuntu-html5-app-launcher --www=www
```

Error:

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".
>   Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
>   Aborted (core dumped)

Situation:

I'm extremely newbie to Ubuntu itself,cannot figure out how to resolve this error.Please help me in simple steps.thanks in advance